# Dataset about Japanese companies

Tags: data-request, economics, companies

Being  mathematician, I suddenly faced a problem with a dataset for the econometric research. Specifically, I'm looking for a dataset about Japanese companies containing such fields as revenue, EBITDA, income, export, R&D investment, etc. Do you have any ideas where to search for something like that? The data may be a bit old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aswath Damodaran, Professor of Finance at the Stern School of Business at New York University, has been compiling corporate data on corporations worldwide into (FREE) datasets and providing them online since 1998.

You can find this information on Japanese firms (3258 companies), as well as other countries at this page:

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/data.html

The Japan Statistics Bureau publishes annual aggregated data on R&D expenditures by industry sector. The information is available online starting with 2004:

http://www.stat.go.jp/english/data/kagaku/index.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have you, by chance, seen a dataset with information about investment in R&D in Japan?

Comment: @KirillLykov - I updated my answer to include R&D info from Statistics Japan. I don't know of a (free) resource for individual firms.

Comment: Download page for the Japanese stats: http://www.e-stat.go.jp/SG1/estat/GL08020103.do?_toGL08020103_&tclassID=000001008300&cycleCode=0&requestSender=search

Answer (score 2):

If you can also work with APIs, rather than downloadable datasets, then you could try [this API](https://rapidapi.com/appaio/api/japan-company-data/).

It accesses the Hojin (Government database), so covers all registered entities in Japan, not just the 3258 mentioned above.